# Centering text around a point

Tags: html, css

Consider this:

```
<div id="point">
    <div class="caption">Caption here</div>
</div>
```

Position is set on `#point`:

```css
#point{
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Now I want the text to be horizontally centered around the it. I tried making the `div` zero width

```css
#point > .caption{
    width: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But apparently this doesn't work. So how do I center the text? It doesn't have to have two `div`s. It's just that I used two `div`s in attempt to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `transform`, we can horizontally (and/or vertically) center text around what would normally be its upper left corner (the point you are talking about).

The red dot (with the `block` class) is added to show the point we're centering around.

```css
.caption {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<span class="caption">Caption here</span>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Version that uses two elements and relative positioning instead of `transform`:

```css
.caption {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  top: -0.5em;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<span class="caption"><span class="inner">Caption here</span></span>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, although I would prefer one without using `transform` (that requires vendor prefixes).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I just added an alternate method that does not use `transform`.

Comment: Interesting how you used `-0.5em` to move it up by 50%. Never knew you can use it like that.

Comment: I just found out that the `em` trick doesn't work with `div`s with padding.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for my language as it is not excellent. The problem with you in this code

```
     #point > .caption{
    width: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

is the width element. Because you have put wrong value. Delete the width attribute or change the value to auto. I hope that I understand what are saying. Best of luck!